# How do I use the Android Percent Support Library with ImageViews?

Tags: android, layout, android-support-library

Not sure how to use the Percent Support Library properly. I successfully compiled it in gradle on version 23.0.0. I keep trying to use percents with ImageView but I keep getting the message: layout_height must be defined. I was under the impression that you would not have to use that attribute if you defined app_heightPercent, so what gives?

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_black_1000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/connected_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_connected_notification" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_display" />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you need this in both your ImageViews?  Also, not sure if you can use this for both width, and height at same time (but not sure)

Comment: What does the message say? which element should have layout_height?

Comment: It says my display ImageView should have layout_height and layout_width. Basically it doesn't recognize that I am using the app:layout_Percents instead.

Comment: You can always provide layout_height="0dp" and layout_width="0dp" it will not effect percentage.

Comment: That's a good point Sharj. Maybe I'll just try that for now.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up on this question while searching for a problem I'm having..found the answer in comments..so here's the answer:

Use `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_width="0dp"`

it won't affect the percentage attributes

Answer (score 0):

For now just ignore these errors, there will be an future update where these issues will be resolved. you will find supporting comments in the following link

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ZQS29a5yroK